# ¿Como realizar una consulta sql con la clausula LIKE usando consultas preparadas en php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Me gustaría saber como puedo realizar una consulta prepara en mysql usando la clausula LIKE para filtrar

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ARTICULOS WHERE DESARROLLO LIKE :search ");
        $search_ = '%'.$name.'%';
        $stmt->bindParam(":search",$search_,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento? , Puedes mostrar tu código?

Comment: ya te lo enseño

Comment: Jhon no entiendo ¿por qué no tu funcionaba? El código es correcto, lo acabo de probar y me funciona.  ¿Cuál era el error en sí?

Answer (score 1):

Pruebe lo siguiente:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * * FROM ARTICULOS WHERE DESARROLLO LIKE :search");
$search = '%SUVALOR%';
$stmt->bindValue(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

---

**Otro ejemplo:**

Tienes que incluir los signos `%` en el `$params`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE direccion LIKE ? OR direccion LIKE ?";
$params = array("%$valor1%", "%$valor2%");
$stmt = $handle->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Si observara la consulta generada en este código anterior, se vería algo así como:  `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE direccion LIKE '%"calle1"%' OR direccion LIKE '%"calle2"%'`, porque la declaración preparada está citando sus valores dentro de una cadena ya citada.

Comment: Estuvo perfecto me funciono correctamente muchas gracias!

Comment: @JhonDemberMurilloMendez me alegra, no olvide calificar la respuesta y marcar como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), para ayudar a otros usuarios que puedan tener la misma duda, Saludos!

Comment: Me volví loco con las consultas preparas y el Like, esto me ha solucionado el problema. Funciona a la perfección.
¿Lo que no entiendo como se interpreta %$variable% es una concatenación? Estos operadores % como los interpreta PHP?